# How to cluster similar file paths?

Tags: python

In a directory, I have several folders. from the middle section of the long list of folder paths, usually there is a semi-structured pattern that emerges which shares a common parent folder. There is only a set of folder names possible, only the arrangement and length of the path is unique. Here's an example list:

```
/project/a/b/static <--- not part of any chunk due to missing '(integer)' in /b/
/project/a/b/a/static <--- not part of any chunk

/project/a/b(1)/static
/project/a/b(1)/linked
/project/a/b(1)/flat

/project/c/c  <--- not part of any chunk

/project/a/b(2)/static
/project/a/b(2)/linked
/project/a/b(2)/flat

/project/a/b(3)/static
/project/a/b(3)/linked
/project/a/b(3)/unique <--- part of this chunk due to same parent folder names
/project/a/b(3)/flat

/project/a/b(4)/static
/project/a/b(4)/linked
/project/a/b(4)/flat

/project/a/a/a/a/a/linked <---- not part of any chunk
```

Basically what I'd like to do is figure out "chunks" of similar folder paths separated in the manner above. So the end result would be something like a list of "chunks", with the outliers removed.

This is the pseudocode I thought of, but I definitely feel like clustering similar paths based on the length of the string or/and some kind of Levenshtein distance.

It appears that I need to do an approximate string matching rather than clustering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming those file paths are in a `list` called `paths` you could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
REGEX = re.compile(r'/b\((\d+)\)/')  # change to match your needs

def path_grouper(path):
    match = REGEX.search(path)
    if match is None:
        return (False, path)
    return (True, int(match.group(1)))
```

Used as:

```
In [6]: for (is_group, key), group in it.groupby(paths, path_grouper):
   ...:     if is_group:
   ...:         print('Got a group with key: {}\n'.format(key))
   ...:         for path in group:
   ...:             print(path)
   ...:         print('End group')
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print('Got lonely path:\n')
   ...:         for path in group:
   ...:             print(path)
   ...:             
Got lonely path:

/project/a/b/static
Got lonely path:

/project/a/b/a/static
Got a group with key: 1

/project/a/b(1)/static
/project/a/b(1)/linked
/project/a/b(1)/flat
End group
Got lonely path:

/project/c/c
Got a group with key: 2

/project/a/b(2)/static
/project/a/b(2)/linked
/project/a/b(2)/flat
End group
Got a group with key: 3

/project/a/b(3)/static
/project/a/b(3)/linked
/project/a/b(3)/unique
/project/a/b(3)/flat
End group
Got a group with key: 4

/project/a/b(4)/static
/project/a/b(4)/linked
/project/a/b(4)/flat
End group
Got lonely path:

/project/a/a/a/a/a/linked
```

If you want a more flexible approach you could try to use the [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) standard module. In particular you could use `find_longest_match()` or `get_matching_blocks()` to see where two paths match and try to decide whether they should be grouped.

```
import difflib

def make_path_grouper():
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
    def path_grouper(path):
        if not matcher.a:
            matcher.set_seq1(path)
            return path
        else:
            matcher.set_seq2(path)
            matchings = matcher.get_matching_blocks()
            # arbitrary code to decide whether we have a match
            if any(size > 14 for _,_,size in matchings):
                # we have a match
                return matcher.a
            else:
                # no match. The new path supersedes old "a"
                matcher.set_seq1(path)
                return path
    return path_grouper
```

Example usage:

```
In [15]: for key, group in it.groupby(paths, make_path_grouper()):
    ...:     group = tuple(group)
    ...:     if len(group) > 1:
    ...:         print('Got a block: {}\n'.format(key))
    ...:         for path in group:
    ...:             print(path)
    ...:         print('End block')
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print('Got lonely path:\n')
    ...:         print(key)
Got lonely path:

/project/a/b/static
Got lonely path:

/project/a/b/a/static
Got a block: /project/a/b(1)/static

/project/a/b(1)/static
/project/a/b(1)/linked
/project/a/b(1)/flat
End block
Got lonely path:

/project/c/c
Got a block: /project/a/b(2)/static

/project/a/b(2)/static
/project/a/b(2)/linked
/project/a/b(2)/flat
End block
Got a block: /project/a/b(3)/static

/project/a/b(3)/static
/project/a/b(3)/linked
/project/a/b(3)/unique
/project/a/b(3)/flat
End block
Got a block: /project/a/b(4)/static

/project/a/b(4)/static
/project/a/b(4)/linked
/project/a/b(4)/flat
End block
Got lonely path:

/project/a/a/a/a/a/linked
```

Note that the logic that decides when a group is found can be arbitrary complex and *you* should decide it. I just tried a very simple heuristic using a threshold for the matching size. With `size = 14` it turns out the same output as the code before, but it will obviously be wrong with other inputs.

---

Expanding a bit more the solution, since you want to match only a certain prefix, you can do something like this:

```
def make_path_grouper(prefix_checker):
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
    def path_grouper(path):
        if not matcher.a:
            matcher.set_seq1(path)
            return path
        else:
            matcher.set_seq2(path)
            matchings = tuple(matcher.get_matching_blocks())
            # arbitrary code to decide whether we have a match
            if matchings and prefix_checker(matcher.a[:matchings[0][2]]):
                # we have a match
                return matcher.a
            else:
                # no match. The new path supersedes old "a"
                matcher.set_seq1(path)
                return path
    return path_grouper
```

Then you can define your custom `prefix_checker` that determines if the matching prefix should be considered a group. Some examples:

```
def prefix_length_checker(length):
    """Consider group if the prefix is of at least the given length."""
    return lambda x: len(x) >= length

def prefix_regex_checker(regex):
    """Consider group if the prefix matches a certain regex."""
    return regex.match

def prefix_ratio_checker(pattern, threshold):
    """Consider group if the prefix is "similar" to a given pattern.

    This fundamentally uses an extension of Levenstein distance.
    """
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
    matcher.set_seq1(pattern)
    def check_ratio(prefix, matcher=matcher):
        matcher.set_seq2(prefix)
        return matcher.ratio() >= threshold
    return check_ratio
```

And use them as in:

```
grouper = make_path_grouper(prefix_ratio_checker('/project/a/b/', 0.8))
for key, group in it.groupby(paths, grouper):
```

In your case maybe a `regex` would be enough. You just want to match prefixes that contain the `b(<number>)` part.

It's possible to extend this to check not only the prefix but all matching blocks, however checking the prefix should be enough for your use-case.

Comment: how did you decide on the value 14? I was thinking more along the lines of using clustering algorithm on the levenschtein distances.

Comment: @KimJongWoo *As I **clearly** stated* I chose a *random* method just to show where you should put *your own* code to determine groups. It *happened* that I chose to check match length and tried 3-4 values to obtain a good-looking output, hence the `14`. I believe levenstein distance isn't really suitable for this purpose because you actually want to match a prefix exactly and let everything else match everything. A more sensible choice is to use `get_matching_blocks()` and verify that the correct prefix is matched.